# Stacking Media Queries with CSS3

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm trying to stack media queries in CSS, and can't seem to get it to work correctly. What i'm trying to achieve is having a single set of css rules for **any** of the media queries. I know normally I could use an **and** to have it apply to different rules, but in this case I'm trying to deal with vendor-specific prefixes so the browser won't satisfy all of the conditions.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
@media only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
@media only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1),
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
@media only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
    /* My rules go here */
}
```

What is the correct way to stack rules like this? Also, if there is any further reading on this subject, I'd like to check it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct way is to have only one `@media` at the very beginning, followed by a comma-separated list of media queries:

```
@media only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
       only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1),
       only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
       only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
    /* Your rules go here */
}
```

`@media` is only permitted when declaring a *distinct* media rule, and is not used to separate multiple media queries in a single rule.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the info - is there any documentation that I can read on this?

Comment: @Dan: Here's the Media Queries spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries based on the CSS2 media types spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/media.html